# React Navigation Navigate from Firebase Push Notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-navigation, react-native-push-notification

I can't figure out how to navigate from push notifications from firebase fcm.  I was having issues with navigation being undefined so I followed this guide, but it still doesn't change screens.  Is there some basic step I am missing.  I have tried to navigate to several other screens without params and none navigate, and I am not getting any errors:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Here is my navigation service:

```
this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
  const { data } = notificationOpen.notification;

    NavigationService.navigate("Chat", {
        chatName: `${data.channelName}`,
        chatId: `${data.channelId}`
      });

});
```

And here is my main App file:

```
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';

const TopLevelNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  ChatApp
},
{
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: false,
  }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TopLevelNavigator);

class App extends Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer ref={navigatorRef => {
          NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
        }} />
      </Provider>)
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you make sure onNotificationOpened triggered?

Comment: Yes.  It is triggered every time I click on the push notification.   I can see the variables inside using alert as well

Comment: I dont see issue with your code. You could try to debug inside NavigationService to see what is going on.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to use debugger since upgrading to >.60 react native since firebase isn't supporting the library I am using anymore (for authentication and there is a network error when I use debugger) and didn't want to mess with authentication.  I have placed a bunch of alerts and those fire as expected so I am not sure what's going on.  Do I need to edit stack navigator?

Comment: Could you show all of your navigator?

Comment: So the issue was that I didn't have ChatScreen in my navigator.  I thought when I used the service I didn't need it in the same navigator/ it acted similar to withNavigation

Comment: Obviously, when you `navigate` to a screen, it must be defined in your navigator

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I needed to have the other stack inside of the same navigator.  Once I added that it started working

```
const TopLevelNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  ChatApp: {
    screen: ChatApp,
  },
  Chat: {
    screen: ChatScreen,
  }
});
```